# Cumulative distribution function - why is it so important?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Why CDF is so imporant that it's defined before probability density function in most textbooks? What makes it so important? Was it defined in that way just for practical reasons, or there is a deeper, mathematical reason of how it's defined?

Comment: Does every real-valued random variable have a CDF? 
Does every real-valued random variable have a PDF?

Comment: At the level of treatment of probability in undergraduate probability textbooks, the CDF is important because "every" random variable (whether discrete or continuous or mixed) has a CDF, and the CDF can be used to provide a unified treatment that is applicable to all random variables. For example, $$E[X]=\int_0^\infty [1-F_X(x)]\,\mathrm dx-\int_{-\infty}^0 F_X(x)\,\mathrm dx$$ from which the various special cases $$E[X]=\sum_i x_ip_X(x_i) \quad \text{or} \quad E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_X(x)\,\mathrm dx$$ can be deduced.