# Why is Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) important from a practical standpoint?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am wondering why is CDF important from a practical point of view. I am aware of the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089800/cumulative-distribution-function-why-is-it-so-important) and I also agree that

$E[X]=\int_0^\infty [1-F_X(x)]\,\mathrm dx-\int_{-\infty}^0 F_X(x)\,\mathrm dx$
and $P(a<X\le b] = F(b) - F(a).$

So CDF is important. However, to find the CDF, one requires its pdf. So what is the use of CDF from a practical point of view. Or, are there physical settings where pdf is not known but only CDF is known?

Any response in this connection is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, we don't need pdf to find cdf. Cdf always exists, unlike pdf.

Comment: Many random variables don’t even have pdfs.

Comment: Cdfs are easy to reliably estimate from data, and pdfs, even when they exist, are not.

Comment: Also, in hypothesis testing, the power of the test can be expressed using an appropriate CDF

Comment: You ask about "physical" settings: In a typical "intro to probability" kind of course, about half the course would be devoted to discrete random variables, e.g. the result of a die roll, or the number of Heads in $n$ flips of a fair coin.  These variables (like all variables) have a CDF, and they do not have a pdf (unless you include more advanced mathematical objects like Dirac deltas).

Comment: @StubbornAtom I agree that we don't need pdf to define CDF as $F(x) = P(X\le x)$. But then we need the probability measure $P$. In a physical setting, in continuous case, how do we know $P$ without knowing the pdf? Please remember I am talking from a practical point of view.

Comment: @user658409 Yes I know. My question is, is there a physical setting where only cdf is known but not the pdf.

Comment: @kimchilover "Cdfs are easy to reliably estimate from data, and pdfs, even when they exist, are not." This is interesting. Can you elaborate it in the form of an answer?

Comment: Can you elaborate what "from a practical point of view" means?  Are you asking about what comes up in the day-to-day activities of a theoretical probabilist?  Or of a data-analyst /applied statistician?  Or of an applied scientist in a lab?  Or university lecturer, trying to be a bit of all the above to his students in lectures?

Comment: (1) If you're looking only at continuous r.v.s, how about the exponential distribution and the memory-less property?  I think the most natural definition of the memory-less property is $P(X > x) = a^x$ for some $a < 1$ i.e. exponential decay.  This is $1 - CDF$ and the pdf is derived from it. (2) As to estimating CDF vs pdf, imagine you have $1000$ different numbers each with $5$ significant digits.  The CDF shape is well defined and natural-looking, but the pdf shape (histogram) will depend a lot on your bin size -- if your bin size is too small, you end up with $1000$ separate "impulses".

Comment: @kimchilover Yes the later one: A university lecturer trying to emphasise the importance of CDFs in an introductory probstat. course from a theoretical probabilist or a data-analyst /applied statistician or an applied scientist in a lab.

Comment: @antkam Very nice motivation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space. A random variable is a function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ which is $(\mathcal F, \lambda)$-measurable, where $\lambda$ denotes Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$. $X$ induces a probability measure $\mu_F$ on $\mathbb R$ by $\mu_F((-\infty,x])=\mathbb P(X\leqslant x)$, where we denote $F_X(x):= \mathbb P(X\leqslant x)$. This is called the distribution function of $X$, and is defined for all random variables.

If $\mu_F$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, that is, $\lambda(A)=0$ implies $\mu_F(A)=0$, then because $\mu_F$ and $\lambda$ are $\sigma$-finite, there exists a measurable function $f:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ such that for any Lebesgue measurable set $A$, $\mu_F(A) = \int_A f\ \mathsf d\lambda$. This function $f$ is called the probability density of $X$. Note that this does not always exist, in particular in the case where $X$ is a discrete random variable (taking values in a countable set).

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I know all of these. I have done a measure theoretic probability course. As mentioned in the comments, I am a university lecturer trying to emphasise the importance of CDFs in a introductory probstat. course.